# Use custom values as units?

Tags: units

Does Blender have any way of using custom units? Say I create a "unit" called depth and set it to equal 5mm. I set an object to have the dimensions (1 depth, 5 depth, 3 depth) which would equal (5mm, 25mm, 15mm). Then I change depth to equal 6mm. The object dimensions would change to (6mm, 30mm 18mm). Does blender have anything like that?

Comment: [Drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/index.html) might take you part of the way, but Blender doesn't really have any procedural or editable objects, so unless you can do it all with modifiers you will probably have a hard time achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

Blender only has 1 unitless unit: the ***B***lender **U**nit.
You can't create any others, but that doesn't matter, since it does exactly what you want.

At first your BU equals 5mm. Enter `0.005` in the **Unit Scale** checkbox.

[image]

Switching between *metric* and *None* will you either Dimensions of (1, 5, 3) or (5mm, 25mm, 15mm).

Changing the translating to `1 BU = 6mm` seems pretty straightforward. Simply entering the new value `0.006` produces dimensions of (6mm, 30mm 18mm).

[image]